# Using html-webpack-plugin and favicons-webpack-plugin with craco but not working on index.html

Tags: javascript, webpack, create-react-app, html-webpack-plugin, craco

Hello and thank you for reading this.

So, I want to use the combination of [html-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin) and [favicons-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/jantimon/favicons-webpack-plugin#html-injection) to inject the manifest and different resolutions of favicons into my app.

I'm trying with this configuration

```
/* craco.config.js */
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const FaviconsWebpackPlugin = require("favicons-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
  babel: {
    plugins: [["@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators", { legacy: true }]],
  },
  webpack: {
    plugins: [
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        title: "My App",
        template: "./public/index.html",
        filename: "admin.html",
        meta: {
          viewport: "width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no",
          // Will generate: <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
          "theme-color": "#4285f4",
          // Will generate: <meta name="theme-color" content="#4285f4">
        },
      }),
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        title: "My App",
        template: "./public/index.html",
        filename: "admin2.html",
        meta: {
          viewport: "width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no",
          // Will generate: <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
          "theme-color": "#4285f4",
          // Will generate: <meta name="theme-color" content="#4285f4">
        },
      }),
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        title: "My App",
        template: "./public/index.html",
        filename: "index.html",
        meta: {
          viewport: "width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no",
          // Will generate: <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
          "theme-color": "#4285f4",
          // Will generate: <meta name="theme-color" content="#4285f4">
        },
      }),
      new FaviconsWebpackPlugin({
        logo: "./src/logo.svg", // svg works too!
        prefix: "icons/",
        inject: true,
        favicons: {
          appName: "my-app",
          appDescription: "My awesome App",
          developerName: "Me",
          developerURL: null, // prevent retrieving from the nearest package.json
          background: "#ddd",
          theme_color: "#333",
          icons: {
            coast: false,
            yandex: false,
          },
        },
      }),
    ],
  },
};
```

And the test is resulting in weird unexpected results. In the documents admin and admin2 the results are the ones expected but on index, seems like my plugins are being overwritten.

[image]

I'm not sure if I'm doing it incorrectly, This is my first time working with [craco](https://github.com/gsoft-inc/craco/blob/master/packages/craco/README.md#installation). Thank you so much in advance

You can see my repo at https://github.com/GunB/PageGroup-Test-0520/tree/1-Layout

Comment: I am facing the same problem, have you figured it out?